# table is marked as crashed and should be repaired

Tags: cartthrob, login, mysql

All of a sudden I cannot log into my control panel.  Does anyone have any advice as to where I could start to get this repaired?

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 145

Table './db-name/exp_cartthrob_cart' is marked as crashed and should be repaired

SELECT `cart` FROM (`exp_cartthrob_cart`) WHERE `id` = '3099' LIMIT 1

Filename: third_party/cartthrob/models/cart_model.php

Line Number: 28
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet would be to attempt to repair the table via a database management utility outside of the EE control panel. Does your web host offer anything like a PHPMyAdmin interface, or do you have any experience with standalone MySQL clients like [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/)? Those utilities should expose table repair functionality. I'd start there first.

Before you proceed beyond this point, I probably cannot emphasize enough that you **back up your database**. If you don't know how to do this, ask. The following could potentially further complicate the issue, and it would be best if you had a semi-safe point to roll back to.

That said, you could modify the following script with your database credentials, upload it to your server, and execute it:

```
<?php

// Taking the information in brackets from your /system/expressionengine/config/database.php

$db_con = mysql_connect('[YOUR DB HOSTNAME]', '[YOUR DB USERNAME]', '[YOUR DB PASSWORD]');
mysql_select_db('[YOUR DATABASE NAME]',$db_con);

$q_result = mysql_query('REPAIR TABLE exp_cartthrob_cart');

if ( ! $q_result )
{
    die('Total failure. I recommend panic.');
} else {
    echo mysql_result($q_result,0) . ' has been repaired.';
}
```